# onChange not Firing with Richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

What's wrong with the following code ?
I am trying to fire an onchange event but it doesn't fire.
Any tricks?

```
<h:inputText id="productIdField" required="false" styleClass="txt" >
    <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
    <rich:toolTip showDelay="500"  styleClass="bgcolor-white">
    </rich:toolTip>
    <a:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"  requestDelay="250" action="testChange();"/>
    </h:inputText>
```

Javascript :

```
function testChange(){

                alert('TestChange');

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action` attribute is used for referencing a method in some bean which should be invoked when `event` is triggered, not a javascript function. From the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/support.html)

> type: javax.el.MethodExpression 
>   (signature must match java.lang.Object action()) - MethodBinding pointing at the application action to be invoked...

Example:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.text}">
      <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="output" action="#{bean.action}"/>
</h:inputText>
```